# make android notification stay until user clears it

Tags: android, notifications, alert

My question is regarding Notification and `NotificationManager`,
in my app I use a Notification to alert the user, but it plays the mp3 I gave it only once, and vibrates only ones, I wish it to play a sound and vibrate until the user clear the Notification by pressing clear. I couldn't find an example that simplified it, what's the best way to achieve that?

Thank All that reply,
Amitos80

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there are flags you can set for achieving desired result,

```
Notification notification = new Notification(mIcon, mTickerText, mWhen);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(mContext, mContentTitle, mContentText, mContentIntent);
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; 
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
mNotificationManager.notify(ID, notification);
```

This will work definitely.

If you find it useful dont forget to mark it as an answer.

Comment: "This will work definitely." -- no, it will not. It should be `Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL|Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT`. The first flag handles the "until the user clear the Notification by pressing clear" part. The second flag handles the "I wish it to play a sound and vibrate until the user clear the Notification" part. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_INSISTENT